# Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for multiple variables

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

We have $e(p,u): \mathbb R^N \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $h(p,u): \mathbb R^N \times \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R^N$ such that $h(p,u) = \triangledown_pe(p,u)$ Suppose we have $p^0$ and $p^1$ such that every element of the two vectors are the same except $p^0_1$ and $p^1_1$, so $p^0_j = p^1_j$ with $j = 2, 3,..., N$. Assume that both functions are continuous and differentiable. We can write:

$$e(p^0, u^1) - e(p^1,u^1) = \int^{p^0_1}_{p^1_1}{h_1(p,u^1)dp_1}$$

I know that this is an application of Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, but the one I am familiar with is single-variable version. Could someone explain why the above is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus you know. You have, by definition of the gradient, 
$$
h_1(p,u)=D_{p_1}e(p,u).
$$
Then
$$
e(p^0, u^1) - e(p^1,u^1) = \int^{p^0_1}_{p^1_1}D_{p_1} \,e(p,u^1)\,dp_1= \int^{p^0_1}_{p^1_1}{h_1(p,u^1)dp_1}
$$

Comment: I was about to delete the question since I suddenly realized they kept the other p constant, but it was already answered. Thanks a lot for this though!